# How to Access textarea from another class?

Tags: java, jpanel, awt, jbutton, jtextarea

main class:

```
public class tuna {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();           
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.add(new apple());
        frame1.setSize(200  , 240);    
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
public class apple extends JPanel{
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black); 
     apple(){
         setBorder(blackline);
         System.out.println("apple");
         ta.setText("hello");
         ta.setEditable(false);
         add(ta);
         add(new doctor());
         repaint();
         revalidate();      
    }
}
```

3rd class

```
    public class doctor extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public JButton butt = new JButton("change");
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black); 
    public doctor(){
        setBorder(blackline);
        add(butt);
    }   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
        if(e.getSource() == butt)
        {   
           System.out.println("she");
        }

    }
}
```

Why everytime the button is pressed it wont print "she" in the console. 
I need my program to change the text inside the text area every time the button is pressed. 
for example when I pressed the button it should append "world" in the text area please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about this, who is responsible for updating the `JTextArea`, `apple` or `doctor`?

If you answered `apple` then you're right, `apple` should maintain control over the component and control access to it.

In extension, `doctor` has no reason to know or care about `apple` or what it can do, it just needs the ability to provide notification to interested parties that some condition has changed, it should not care what other classes do with that information, as it's beyond the scope of its general responsibility.

This is a classic example of an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), where one (or more) interested parties observe changes to another and take action upon them.

Now, the question is, how to best achieve this?  There are a number of solutions, you could roll your own listener `interface`, you could use a pre-existing listener, like `ChangeListener` or you could use the inbuilt functionality provided by the components.  Which you choose will depend on your requirements, to keep it simple, I'm using the last one...

When you create an instance of `doctor`, you can add a `PropertyChangeListener` to it...

```
doctor doc = new doctor();
doc.addPropertyChangeListener("change", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Object newValue = evt.getNewValue();
        if (newValue instanceof String) {
            ta.setText(newValue.toString());
        } else if (newValue == null) {
            ta.setText(null);
        }
    }
});
add(doc);
```

In your `butt` `ActionListener`, you would trigger a `PropertyChangeEvent`...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
    if(e.getSource() == butt)
    {   
        // If you want to, you could pass the "old" value
        firePropertyChange("change", null, "she");
    }
}
```

As one possible example...

Comment: this solved the problem! but how about if i wanted to append a text to it instead of changing the whole text?

Comment: @PNC No worries, it's easy to miss

Answer (score 3):

You must specify listener for the button:

```
butt.addActionListener(this)
```

To do change in text area, you must do field `ta` public:

```
public JTextText ta;
```

Pass `apple` instance to `doctor` instance when creating:

```
new doctor(this)
```

And then save reference to that instance in `doctor`:

```
private apple instance;
```

In `actionPerformed` method you can do manipulations with text area:

```
instance.ta.setText("Some text.");
```

Or you can add method to your `apple` class to set text to text area:

```
public void setTextAreaText(String text) {
    ta.setText(text);
}
```

And in `actionPerformed`:

```
instance.setTextAreaText("Some text.");
```

Note: Think about class & varialbe naming: [old doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: thanks about that it solved a minor problem and it should be butt.addActionListener(this)

Comment: *"To do change in text area, you must do field ta public:"* That's not true and in fact is probably the second worst thing you could do (`static` be the worst).  You should avoid, as much as possible, exposing UI elements to external modification.  This now allows code to do all sorts of nasty things to the `JTextArea`, like removing it from it's parent container or moving to a new container.  The responsibility for the management of the component is the container class, other classes wanting to change should do so via setters...

Comment: I wrote setter as you say? And anyway, IMHO, I do not see any sense in the author's code to observe smth.

Comment: True, but also expose to components to areas of the code that do not need access to them, nor should care. There are better solutions available...

Comment: Forgive my "anal retentiveness", I've spent the better part of 6 years undoing these kind of mistakes from people who should have known better so it grinds on me when I see it ;)